# :nth-child definition & when it meets tr and caption

Tags: css, css-selectors

with the code below I found I'm confused with the definition of `:nth-child`

> The `:nth-child(n)` selector matches every element that is the *nth* child, regardless of type, of its parent.

```css
tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: gray;
}
table {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border: thin solid black;
  caption-side: bottom;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  border: thin dotted gray;
  padding: 5px;
}
caption {
  font-style: italic;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption>content</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>table head</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111111</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222222</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>333333</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>444444</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555555</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>666666</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and the *111111*, *333333*, *555555* become gray. nothing changed after I delete the caption tag, but *222222*, *4444444*, *666666* become gray after I removed the `tr` tag of `table` title. Isn't `:nth-child` suppose to count *every* element of its parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your HTML is invalid. `tr` elements must be wrapped within either a `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot` element, and most browsers will automatically *fix* this for you by sticking them in a `tbody`.

Your HTML on these browsers will actually end up looking like this:

```
<table>
  <caption>...</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And thus, deleting the `<caption>` element will have no impact on the positioning of your `tr` elements.

If you inspect your `<table>` element, this is what you'll see:

[image]

Comment: so true! I viewed my HTML in the developer tools of Chrome and saw the tbody tag without paying attention to it... thx a lot! maybe I should validate my code first before asking